# How can I use NASM as a library?

Tags: c++, assembly, nasm

I would like to include NASM itself (the assembler) in a C++ project.  Can I compile NASM as a shared library?  If not, is there another assembler that works as a C or C++ library?

I checked [libyasm](http://yasm.tortall.net/) but couldn't understand how I can use it to assemble my code.

Comment: You want to add assembler code written in NASM to a library or you want to add NASM itself to a library so that the program which is using the library is able to interpret assembly code?

Comment: The latter; I want to use NASM as a library.

Comment: regards bounty - specifically an x86 & x64 capable assembler that can be included in Windows (VC++) and Linux.

Comment: please define *NASM as a library*

Comment: http://yasm.tortall.net/ says `Many of the modular interfaces at least superficially finished. This is still an area that needs a lot of work.`, so I'd guess that libyasm isn't ready for prime time.  Still, [there is a github repo for it](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/wiki/Libyasm) that doesn't say anything about it not being ready for use.  I'd guess that spending more time on libyasm would be worth it, since it definitely says its designed to work as a library.

Comment: @Orwellophile: have you looked at LLVM?  It can't handle NASM syntax, but it probably works with AT&T syntax, or GAS-style Intel syntax.  There's also LLVM-IR, aka LLVM assembly language, which is a platform-independent thing that the LLVM optimizer can use to generate code for any platform.

Comment: @Orwellophile: You said "assemble bytecode"; did you mean assemble source TO machine code?

Comment: @Orwellophile:  LLVM is designed for JIT-compiling code that will be run in the context of the process that created it, rather than for creating object files, but you can probably do both.  I mean, clang is built on top of LLVM.  Which do you need?

Comment: The bounty seems to be a slightly different question from the original. The original code didn't seem to say anything about generating byte code. The original I believe was more about assembling code via a library rather than assembling via NASM externally.

Comment: I don't see the point of turning NASM into a library. If you have, say, a function named `assemble_with_nasm`, does it matter if it does it job by running code in the same process or by running NASM as normal in a separate process?

Comment: I could care less what the OP wanted, I'm the one offering the bounty.  But perhaps byte-code was the wrong term.  I meant that the output need only be raw bytes (preferably in memory) representing the assembled code.  No ELF/WinPE/Linker stuff required. The "point" is to achieve something similar to [Cheat Engine](https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine).  I don't think a NASM library is good idea either!  Something much simpler is called for.  Think: **the opposite of distorm3** and **don't even think about AT&T syntax**

Comment: @PeterCordes LLVM and Clang?  Wow, huge.  I didn't specify NASM, that was the OP.  But I think the broader question deserves an answer, because I spent 2+ hours googling the subject and this SO question was the closest I came to an answer.   I could find you 4 opensource x86/64 disassembly libraries in 2 minutes, but where are the matching *re-assemblers* (ok, not really a word, but i'm hoping it conveys the level of simplicity that would be reasonable for a library/dll/shared library)

Comment: @Orwellophile: Depending on how modular libyasm is, it should be able to assemble a "flat binary" into a buffer in memory.  This sort of this is what LLVM is designed for, but like I said it doesn't support NASM syntax, only GNU-style `.intel_syntax noprefix`, where e.g. `mov eax, OFFSET symbol` is needed to generate `mov eax, imm32` instead of a load.

Comment: @Orwellophile  Do you want to actually execute this code in the context of the process that assembled it?  Do you need it to resolve references to global symbols that aren't defined in the chunk of asm?  It sounds like you should have asked a new question where you could specify all these things, instead of trying to repurpose an old question that wasn't specific enough.

Comment: @Orwellophile If you want to put your own conditions on a question (or change the parameters of a question), why didn't you post a NEW question and put a bounty on it. Then we don't need to figure out what you want and how it differs from the original question asked.

Comment: I do not believe this deviates from the OP's original request. I have merely reduced the requirements.  The bounty is on THIS question is because it did not receive enough attention.   The OP's question, was if NASM could be included as a library, or if there was another assembler that could be. @MichaelPetch - if I did not add 'conditions' then we might all be searching for an assembler that also compiles on Sparc and PowerPC (as NASM does), and is capable of compiling COFF, Portable Executable, a.out, Executable and Linkable Format (ELF), and Mach-O.  How would that help anyone?

Comment: @PeterCordes no, I'm not looking for dynamic execution, or linkage to external variables, or anything that would exceed even the scope of stand-alone NASM.  I will provide another example: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm which actually uses GCC and objdump behind the scenes, but note that you can paste the output from the disassembler into the assembler.  It also accept `labels:`, the only other required item is the ability to set the offset or base-address.  (No, mov eax, OFFSET symbol is not cool, but I'm willing to accept `mov RAX, QWORD PTR label1`).

Comment: @Orwellophile: If you don't like `mov eax, OFFSET symbol`, then you can't use LLVM (unless you write a text preprocessor that converts NASM syntax to GAS-intel syntax).  It sounds like you should look harder at libyasm.

Comment: @Orwellophile: Since you did need to add conditions in your bounty, you should have asked a new question, even though it's very similar to this one.  We could have later marked this one as a duplicate of your new more specific question.  That would have given you space to lay out your requirements in bullet-point form in a question, instead of in comments here.

Comment: @PeterCordes: In all fairness, if anyone can provide a solution to the OP's original question (and qualifying comment), I will still award the bounty.  I also appreciate that at this point, a new question with precision specs would be an excellent idea.  But I hope you will concede that those specs would never have been of adequate precision without our in-comment discourse.  And remember, **You can now assemble x86 code even easier by [tweeting](https://twitter.com/plzasm)**

Comment: I retract that, the bounty has been removed by a higher power.

Comment: @Orwellophile: This question was specifically asking about NASM, not the general question.  I tried to broaden it after you put a bounty on it, but it didn't really work well without your clarifications in comments.  This question had near-zero value, with no comments or answers, so there was no good reason to try to repurpose it instead of writing a new question.  [The twitter bot is just a frontend for gcc with `.intel_syntax noprefix`](https://github.com/redragonx/plzasm/blob/master/libs/assemblyLib.php), so what's your point?

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, only I noticed you made that edit after my last comment. Thanks for that. My requirements aside, I'm confident that is what the OP would have wanted.  The twitterbot thing - no point, other than some kind of vague irony that we can't replicate in a library what a twitter bot is doing.   Anyway, I do appreciate your assistance, I'll confess I've been adverse to LLVM since I moved to OS X as it takes 8 gig to compile.  yasm does actually have a lot of potential (once you get it to build) and I will submit an answer to this question once I read the code and work it out.  Thx.

Comment: @Orwellophile: You already said that needing `mov eax, OFFSET symbol` wasn't an option, so the twitterbot doesn't do what you need.  Besides that, like Ross already pointed out, it's not hard to write a library function that forks off a process to assemble something with gcc or NASM, like the twitterbot does.  It's obviously much harder to include the code for the assembler inside the same process, rather than talking to it through a pipe.  Anyway, yeah hopefully you can come up with a good answer to this, probably with libyasm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Woah, this exploded when I was away.

I had solved this problem by tampering with the YASM source code, and totally forgot about the question in SO as it received absolutely no attention 8 months ago. Below are the details, followed by a **better suggestion**.

For the project that I had in mind, I needed to use YASM as a library, and I was in a hurry because I was doing this for a company. Back then there were no good libraries that I was aware of; and I had concluded that getting used to the LLVM framework was an overkill for the task (because all I wanted was to assemble singular x86 - x86_64 instructions and receive the bytes).

So I downloaded the source code for YASM.

Upon meddling with the code for a while, I noticed that the executable receives the file paths for input and output files; and passes these two strings along. I wanted char arrays in memory for the input and output; not files. So I figured, maybe if I could find all FILE pointers that are passed around, I can convert them to char pointers, and change every file read/write to array operations.

This turned out to be even more cumbersome than it sounds. Apparently YASM does not open input/output files once and uses the same FILE pointers; instead it passes around copies of the filepath strings. I needed a script that could make all the necessary changes for me, this wasn't good for me.

Eventually, I found all fopen/fclose calls in the program with a script, and replaced them with my_fopen/my_fclose. For each file that I made these replacements, I included my header file in which I implemented these two functions.

In both of these functions, I checked the incoming string, compared it with "fake_file". If they are equal, I passed a 'fake' FILE pointer pointing to two portions of memory, obtained from the function calls fmemopen and open_memstream. Otherwise I simply called the actual fopen/fclose functions. In other words, I redirected these two calls (only for a given filename) to a memory file. Then, I called the library with the filename parameter set to 'fake_file'.

Since I have had limited myself to Linux at that point, this approach worked for me. I also found out (using Valgrind) that there was a memory leak in the library version, so I wrote a very primitive garbage collector for it. Basically I wrapped malloc's etc. to keep track of all allocations that are not freed, and clean them after each execution.

This approach also allowed me to automate these changes using a script. Unfortunately I did all these in a company so I cannot leak any actual code.

**Better suggestion:**
As of May 31, 2016; you can use Keystone Engine instead. It is "based on LLVM, but it goes much further with a lot more to offer." The disassembly engine Capstone and this are a near perfect couple for assembly and disassembly. If you need either of these components, I suggest these instead of doing the hacks I described. Both of these engines are currently being developed; and even though Keystone has some small bugs, Capstone is very robust at the moment.

**TL;DR:** Use [keystone](http://www.keystone-engine.org).